# Can't returning a tree node when is found

Tags: c, return, structure, binary-tree

How can I return a tree node when I found it?

So, I have a binary tree and, when I search in the tree what I searched for was found I want to return the pointer to that node, so I can usa that node in other function. There is my search function:

```
Tnode *Tsearch(Tnode *r, char *word) {
    if(r == NULL) {
        printf("%s NOT FOUND\n", word);
        return NULL;
    }
    int comp = strcasecmp(r->word, word);
    if( comp == 0) {
        printf("%s FOUND\n", r->word);
        return r;
    }
    else if( comp > 0) {
        Tsearch(r->left, word);
    }
    else if( comp < 0) {
        Tsearch(r->right, word);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that when I try to use the return of the function Tsearch it doesn't work and I really can't understand why and how to solve it.

The function where I want to use that returned node from the search function is the following:

```
int Tsearch_ref(Tnode *r, char (*words)[30]) {
    if(r == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    printf("%s, %d", words[0], (int)strlen(words[0]));
    Tsearch(r,words[0]);
    auxT = Tsearch(r,words[0]);
    Lnode *aux = auxT->head;
    printf("Title: %s\n", ((Book *)aux->ref)->title);
    while(aux != NULL) {
        aux_arr[i].ref=aux->ref;
        printf("Title: %s\n", ((Book *)aux_arr[i].ref)->title);
        printf("%p\n", &(aux_arr[i].ref));
        aux = aux->next;
        i++;
    }
}
```

This function is not complete because I was trying to solve the return problem, but basically I want to take that tree node that have a list inside and put that list into a temporary array.

The structures are the following:

```
typedef struct {
    char *title;
    char isbn13[ISBN13_SIZE];
    char *authors;
    char *publisher;
    int year;
} Book;

typedef struct lnode {
    struct lnode *next;
    void *ref;
} Lnode;


typedef struct tnode {
    struct tnode *left;
    struct tnode *right;
    char *word;
    Lnode *head;
} Tnode;
```

It's my first question here in StackOverflow, so if you need any more info about anything I will obviously provide it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the recursive calls to Tsearch to actually return the found node.  So, instead of this code:

```
else if( comp > 0) {
    Tsearch(r->left, word);
}
else if( comp < 0) {
    Tsearch(r->right, word);
}
```

do this:

```
else if( comp > 0) {
    return Tsearch(r->left, word);
}
else if( comp < 0) {
    return Tsearch(r->right, word);
}
```

Note that if your tree is very deep, you may use up the entire call stack and throw an exception.

Comment: It solved the error (and I understood why), but now I still have another problem, for example when in the `printf("Title: %s\n", ((Book *)aux->ref)->title);` it doesn't print nothing as I expect. What can be the the reason of that? Thank you again!

Comment: it's impossible to say why you're not getting anything printed out. I guess that you need to step through the code in gdb or some debugger and see what the value of `aux->ref` is.  You might have to create a local variable `Book *b = aux->ref;` to examine the value in the debugger.

Comment: Ok, that's why it's bad to work at late night, `Tsearch_ref` was not printing because I was not calling the function. I realize that after use the debugger. Thank you a lot by the enormous help!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use **while** loop?

```
Tnode *Tsearch(Tnode *r, char *word) {
    Tnode *cur = r;
    int comp;
    while (cur != NULL)
    {
        if ((comp = strcasecmp(cur->word, word)) == 0)
        {
            printf("%s FOUND\n", cur->word);
            return cur;
        }
        else if (comp > 0)
        {
            /* Move to the left child */
            cur = cur->left;
        }
        else
        {
            /* Move to the right child */
            cur = cur->right;
        }
    }
    printf("NOT FOUND\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: My first version was like that, but I had the same problem because I didn't make the `cur = cur->left/right;` so I made that second version and had the same problem! But thank you for the alternative!